# minify also html with vite.js: how to make vite bundle on npm run build delete comments or tabs in html?

Tags: javascript, html, build, vite, rollupjs

I have a javascript project that uses the vite bundle. https://vitejs.dev/

CSS, and JS get minified successfully on https://vercel.com production site

but HTML have still the comments `<!-- comments -->`

> (I am using javascript vanilla, no react)

> I've seen the GitHub issue tab, but do not understand anything (and the thing they technically solve aren't listed on the DOCS webpage)
>
> - here: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/793 (i've saw something like `apply` config, but docs don't show how to use it, or `flush`)

---

basically, I want that dev environment have comments that show the details of something,

but on production, the comments don't get pushed.

---

here I tried to do a simplified example (not a real example) to show the problem:

[image]

why production have the `<!-- <button> -->` while js with all comments get deleted. (and also how to delete spaces, and tabs in HTML for smaller gzip files index.html

---

I want to be like this:

[image]

(here a tool that minify https://www.willpeavy.com/tools/minifier/)

---

if you tried with vite and don't work,

 I will tell you a hint:

> from what I know vite use `rollup` under the hood, so maybe there is a config in rollup that can work well for vite, do you find some docs about it?
>
> I use vite to not care about config or have less config possible, but maybe is this the case to use configs.

Comment: [vite-plugin-html](https://github.com/vbenjs/vite-plugin-html)